# Is it possible that $a$ such that $a^{513} = 1$ is a primitive $100$-th root of $1$ in $\mathbb{Z}/_{101}\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, primitive-roots

Suppose that a is an element of $\mathbb{Z}/_{101}\mathbb{Z}$ such that
$a^{513} = 1$. Is it possible that $a$ is a
primitive $100$-th root of $1$ in $\mathbb{Z}/_{101}\mathbb{Z}$? Either give an example of a primitive element whose
$513$rd power is $1$ or prove that there does not exist such an element.

Ok so I understand that if $a$ is a primitive $100$th root of $1$ in $\mathbb{Z}/_{101}\mathbb{Z}$, then the smallest exponent of $a$ which equals $1$ mod$(101)$ is $100$.
This means that if $a$ is a primitive root, then

$a^{100}=1$ mod$(101)$

So how could I show that? What can I do from here?

Comment: So you know $\text{ord}_{101}(a)=100$. Therefore if $a^k\equiv 1\pmod{101}$, then $100\mid k$. Clearly $k$ can't be $513$.

Comment: Why, very explicitly, does that mean $k≠513 $ ?

Comment: Hint: can you have $a^{13}=1\pmod {101}$ if $a$ is primitive $100$th root?

Comment: @user274933 Because $100\nmid 513$. For contradiction, assume $\text{ord}_{101}(a)=100$ and $a^{513}\equiv 1\pmod{101}$. Then $100\mid 513$, contradiction.